# CA2000 and returned Socket object: how to solve?

Tags: c#, sockets, code-analysis, idisposable, ca2000

I have next function:

```
    public static Socket ConnectSocket(string srvName, int srvPort)
    {
        Socket tempSocket = null;
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

        try
        {
            hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(srvName);

            //// Loop through the AddressList to obtain the supported AddressFamily. This is to avoid
            //// an exception that occurs when the host IP Address is not compatible with the address family
            //// (typical in the IPv6 case).
            foreach (IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
            {
                IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, srvPort);
                if (!ipe.AddressFamily.Equals(AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
                    continue;

                tempSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                tempSocket.Connect(ipe);
                if (tempSocket.Connected)
                {
                    return tempSocket;
                }

                tempSocket.Close();
            }

            throw new ConnectionThruAddressFamilyFailedException();
        }
finally
{
  //I can't close socket here because I want to use it next
}
    }
```

And I obviously have [CA2000 (Dispose objects before losing scope)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) warning during code analyse here.
A returned socket next used to communicate with server. So I can't dispose it here. Even if I'm disposing this object later here I'm having CA2000.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something throws an exception, you neither return the socket *nor* `Close`/`Dispose` it.

Try:

```
try
{
    tempSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream,
                            ProtocolType.Tcp);

    tempSocket.Connect(ipe);
    if (tempSocket.Connected)
    {
        return tempSocket;
    }

    tempSocket.Close();
    tempSocket = null;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    if (tempSocket != null)
        tempSocket.Close();
    throw;
}
```